# Purpose of this [] in fliter

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNj91.jpg)

What is the purpose of [0] when filtering array of objects ?

Comment: Filter returns an array. The guy just wants the first item in the filtered array. It means the same thing as when accessing first item (index zero) in any normal array

Comment: This probably should be changed to use `.find()` instead of `.filter()`, as that will return the first match and then stop its search, whereas this will search and find all matches, then return the first match it found

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This allows you to extract the result from the filter method which returns an array.

for example when I filter 'owl' its returned in an array, so i reference it by index i.e filteredArray[0] to get the string value

```js
let arrayOfAnimals = ['giraffe', 'zebra', 'owl', 'bear'];
let filteredArray = [];

// filter array to get animal that matches 'owl'
filteredArray = arrayOfAnimals.filter(item => item === 'owl')

console.log(filteredArray) //["owl"] 

console.log(filteredArray[0]) // owl
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember: filter() method returns an array, empty or otherwise.

from the image:

```
1. let dish = DISHES.filter(dish=>(dish.id === id))[0]; // = [ ] or [ dish, .. ]
```

***I assume the next step is something like:***

```
2. dish.name // no error in this line even if no dish is found
```

Now if we use find():

```
1. let dish = DISHES.find(dish=>(dish.id === id)); // = undefined or dish
```

Now line 2 will give an error if not dish is found:

```
2. dish.name // TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

This will crash the code.

Though I would prefer to use find() method as:

```
let dish = DISHES.find(dish=>(dish.id === id)) || {};
dish.name // no fatal error
```

Note: find() method exits the loop as soon as the first true condition is satisfied.